# Send email on creation of custom post type and use get_post_meta()

Tags: php, wordpress

I've setup a custom post type and I want to send an email when I publish a post but I want to use some data from the custom fields I've added to that custom post type, including obtaining an email address from a custom field on my custom post.

I've found some code and can get it to send me an email which all works, including sending the Post Title in the subject, but as soon as I include the get_post_meta, the email doesn't get sent.  I've done a lot of reading online to try and find a solution but haven't had any joy, as you can see from my message, I've tried a different option of get_metadata but again this hasn't worked.

One thing I've read is something about the 'transition_post_status' being fired before it's saved the meta data, but I can't find anywhere what I should use instead that still achieves my requirement of only sending an email for a post on the initial publish (I don't want it to send the email more than once).

I'm a complete novice to PHP and everything I've done so far has been through researching/googling to find solutions, so please go easy if this is a really simple solution.  Thanks in advance.

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'wpse_admin_email_once', 10, 3 );
function wpse_admin_email_once( $new, $old, $post ) {
if ( $post->post_type == 'mycustompost' && $new == 'publish' && $old == 'auto-draft' ) {
    
    $emails  = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'email', true);
    $headers = 'From: Name <hello@company.co.uk>';
    $message = get_metadata('mycustompost', $post->ID, 'message', true);
    $subject = wp_strip_all_tags( get_the_title( $post->ID ) );

    wp_mail( $emails, $subject, $message, $headers );

}
}
```

Comment: Try and use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_insert_post/

Comment: Thanks for the help CBroe.  I've used the example on this page which works from the point of view of the get_post_meta, I'm just struggling to get the code to only send an email when a new post is published for my specific posttype.  It's currently sending emails for all post types and for any updates, removals or even when it goes from auto-draft to publish.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You get the whole post object passed in as parameter - so you should be able to easily check the type. And the $update parameter tells you whether this is an existing post being updated, or a new one being created.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand now from the point of view of having the post details (as I said, I'm a complete novice to PHP).  So I think I've sorted the post type, however the $update parameter seems to be set to true on creation of the post, so if I've got it set to false for updates an email isn't sent when one is created which is what I want.  Apologies if I'm missing something obvious here....

Comment: If the $update parameter doesn't help with what you want to achieve, then you could also check the post's current status.

Comment: Thanks, it's very close now.  It's now working for when I create, but also sends updates when I update (doesn't do when I remove anymore which it was previously).  Any ideas on how I can stop that?  I've just been playing around trying different things but haven't had any joy.

Comment: post status == published, and $update == false?

Comment: That's not worked because $update appears to be True on creation.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, checking the user comments, someone there said, _"$update will be true in first time post is published if you are using dashboard because it creates revisions."_ Maybe you can work better with one of these in this situation: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/47572